# Is it possible to have Hazelcast embedded deployment with .NET application

Tags: .net, .net-core, hazelcast

Is it possible to have Hazelcast embedded deployment with .NET application? After reading [topology overview](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Hazelcast_Overview/Hazelcast_Topology.html) my understanding is no, but it's also not stated explicitly. My app scenario is .NET Core running Linux.

Comment: With docker you should be able to "embed it" in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hazelcast member libraries are available only in Java so if you want to embed a member to a business service, its only possible with Java. Other languages, including .Net can use Hazelcast client libraries to access the cluster.